# How to Deserialize from web service JSON array or object?

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7

I created one web service application in windows phone 7. this is JSON array get from belowed uri.
...[{"id":4,"name":"Bangalore"},{"id":1,"name":"Chennai"},{"id":3,"name":"Hyderabad"},{"id":2,"name":"Mumbai"}]...

List item = (List)ds.ReadObject(msnew);
In this line one bug(it says while run).
[image]
There was an error deserializing the object of type.Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

coding:

public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Item
    {           

        [DataMember]
        public int id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://75.101.161.83:8080/CityGuide/Cities?authId=CITY4@$pir*$y$t*m$13GUID*5"));
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       string MyJsonString = e.Result;
      // MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
       DataContractSerializer ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Item));
       MemoryStream msnew = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyJsonString));
       List<Item> item = (List<Item>)ds.ReadObject(msnew);
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in what you're trying to do.

1. You're using `DataContractSerializer` instead of `DataContractJsonSerializer`. The one you're trying to use is expecting XML, not JSON.
2. You're trying to deserialize to a single `Item` and then convert that to a `List<Item>`, rather than an array, which is what json contains.

Try this instead:

```
  var ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Item[]));
  var msnew = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyJsonString));
  Item[] items = (Item[])ds.ReadObject(msnew);
```

If you later wanted to, you could convert the array to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can add System.Json library from Silverlight SDK. 
It isn't compiled for WP7, but for me it is working fine.