# serialization of WCF REST service Data in windows Phone 8 Client

Tags: c#, json, serialization, windows-phone-8, wcf-rest

here is the code on windows Phone client

[image]

The Inner exception says that "**data at the root level is invalid line 1 position 1**"

Comment: Please show your code as a text, not as an image..

Comment: take a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439020/how-to-deserialize-from-web-service-json-array-or-object

Comment: I have used DataContractSerializer instead of DataContractJsonSerializer.

Comment: Post the content your server returns.

Comment: @KarthikDheeraj that's it ..! change your code & try.

Comment: Its Working. Missed Simple thing.